# Redisson memory leak When I try to create client

Tags: java, memory-leaks, redis, netty, redisson

When I try to use Redisson to Connect Redis Server, it some time show me that memory leak error. how can I fix that.
The reproduce code is in below.

#### Expected behavior

It should't have memory leak.

#### Actual behavior

```
[main] ERROR io.netty.util.ResourceLeakDetector  - LEAK: HashedWheelTimer.release() was not called before it's garbage-collected. See http://netty.io/wiki/reference-counted-objects.html for more information.
Recent access records: 
Created at:
    io.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer.<init>(HashedWheelTimer.java:272)
    io.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer.<init>(HashedWheelTimer.java:216)
    io.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer.<init>(HashedWheelTimer.java:195)
    org.redisson.connection.MasterSlaveConnectionManager.initTimer(MasterSlaveConnectionManager.java:318)
    org.redisson.connection.MasterSlaveConnectionManager.<init>(MasterSlaveConnectionManager.java:161)
    org.redisson.connection.SingleConnectionManager.<init>(SingleConnectionManager.java:34)
    org.redisson.config.ConfigSupport.createConnectionManager(ConfigSupport.java:192)
    org.redisson.Redisson.<init>(Redisson.java:122)
    org.redisson.Redisson.create(Redisson.java:159)
    test.main(test.java:32)
```

#### Steps to reproduce or test case

```
    Codec stringCodec = new StringCodec();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        RedissonClient client;
        Config config = new Config();
        config.useSingleServer().setAddress(RedisConfig.Address);
        config.useSingleServer().setPassword(RedisConfig.Password);
        config.setCodec(stringCodec);
        client = Redisson.create(config);

        BatchOptions options = BatchOptions.defaults();
        RBatch pipe = client.createBatch(options);

        pipe.getBucket("test", stringCodec).getAsync();
        BatchResult res = pipe.execute();

        System.out.println(res.getResponses().get(0));

        client.shutdown();

        System.gc();
    }
```

#### Redis version

4.0.10

#### Redisson version

3.7.5

#### Redisson configuration

```
Config config = new Config();
config.useSingleServer().setAddress(RedisConfig.Address);
config.useSingleServer().setPassword(RedisConfig.Password);
config.setCodec(stringCodec);
client = Redisson.create(config);
```

Comment: you should raise this issue onto their library / project page instead

Comment: Because I don't know it's my problem or the library problem.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a bug in Redisson where it creates a lot of `HashedWheelTimer` without closing these. I would open a bug-report there.